# Using replace and fillna in pandas while using multiple filter criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame(result1) where I am trying to execute the following -

```
result1[(result1['investment_class'] == 'Debt') & (result1['total_assets'] <  31860000.0)]['fund_size'].fillna('Small', inplace=True)
```

There values for investment classes can be debt, equity, arbitrage etc and fund size has can have three values small, medium and large. However, for the debt investment class, all the fund sizes are missing. I am attempting to classify them based on the total assets. Anything below the 25th percentile is small, above 75th percentile is large and rest all are medium.

I am running the above line to make the fund size as small for those debt funds whose total asset is less than the 25th percentile value. But the above line does not seem to work. After executing the above line, all the values for the debt funds are still NaN's and no value has been changed.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong, or is there some step that I am missing?

PS - I have also tries the replace function and that's not working either.

**Providing a minimum reproducible sample** - 
Create a data frame -

```
data = [['Debt', 10, 'Small'], ['Debt', 15, np.NaN], ['Debt', 24, 'Large'], 
        ['Equity', 10, 'Small'], ['Equity', 15, 'Small'], ['Equity', 24, 'Large']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['investment_class', 'total_assets', 'fund_size'])
```

I want to replace all investment_class = 'Debt' and total_assets < 20, fund_size as 'Small' -

```
df[(df['investment_class'] == 'Debt') & (df['total_assets'] < 20)]['fund_size'].fillna("Small", inplace=True)
```

The above line runs fine but does not change the NaN to Small. I have also tried the below line using replace, but that does not work either -

```
df[(df['investment_class'] == 'Debt') & (df['total_assets'] < 20)]['fund_size'].replace(np.NaN, "Small", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: I have provided a minimum reproducible sample.